# Is there something like Buffer.LastPositionOf? Find last occurence of character in buffer?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a buffer of type `ReadOnlySequence<byte>`. I want to extract a subsequence (which will contain 0 - n messages) from it by knowing that each message ends with `0x1c, 0x0d`(as described [here](http://healthstandards.com/blog/2007/05/02/hl7-mlp-minimum-layer-protocol-defined/)).

I know the buffer has an extension method [PositionOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.buffersextensions.positionof?view=netcore-3.1) but it

> Returns the position of the first occurrence of `item` in the
> `ReadOnlySequence<T>`.

and I'm looking for a method which returns me the position of the last occurrence. I tried to implement it on my own, this is what I have so far

```
private SequencePosition? GetLastPosition(ReadOnlySequence<byte> buffer)
{
    // Do not modify the real buffer
    ReadOnlySequence<byte> temporaryBuffer = buffer;
    SequencePosition? lastPosition = null;

    do
    {
        /*
            Find the first occurence of the delimiters in the buffer
            This only takes a byte, what to do with the delimiters? { 0x1c, 0x0d }

        */
        SequencePosition? foundPosition = temporaryBuffer.PositionOf(???);

        // Is there still an occurence?
        if (foundPosition != null)
        {
            lastPosition = foundPosition;

            // cut off the sequence for the next run
            temporaryBuffer = temporaryBuffer.Slice(0, lastPosition.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            // this is required because otherwise this loop is infinite if lastPosition was set once
            break;
        }
    } while (lastPosition != null);

    return lastPosition;
}
```

I'm struggling with it. First of all the `PositionOf` method only takes a `byte` but there are two delimiters so I have to pass in a `byte[]`. Next I think I can optimize the loop "somehow".

Do you have any ideas how to find the last occurence of those delimiters?

Comment: If you're looking to extract up to n messages, each ending in that delimeter, doesn't that mean you could look for the first occurrence of that delimeter, extract a message up to that point, and repeat, rather than looking for the last occurrence?

Comment: @JohnH I think the OP already knows how to do that but as mentioned in the question but I think he is looking to find a method that does this under the hood.

Comment: And I think he doesn't know how to deal with `{ 0x1c, 0x0d }` when `PositionOf` only takes a `byte`

Comment: I've updated my answer a bit, Olaf. It may, or may not, be relevant to you.

Comment: thanks, I will give it a try :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went down a giant rabbit hole digging into this, but I managed to come up with an extension method which I think answers your question:

```
using System;
using System.Buffers;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class ReadOnlySequenceExtensions
{
    public static SequencePosition? LastPositionOf(
        this ReadOnlySequence<byte> source,
        byte[] delimiter)
    {
        if (delimiter == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(delimiter));
        }
        if (!delimiter.Any())
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(delimiter)} is empty", nameof(delimiter));
        }

        var reader = new SequenceReader<byte>(source);
        var delimiterToFind = new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(delimiter);

        var delimiterFound = false;
        // Keep reading until we've consumed all delimiters
        while (reader.TryReadTo(out _, delimiterToFind, true))
        {
            delimiterFound = true;
        }

        if (!delimiterFound)
        {
            return null;
        }

        // If we got this far, we've consumed bytes up to,
        // and including, the last byte of the delimiter,
        // so we can use that to get the position of 
        // the starting byte of the delimiter
        return reader.Sequence.GetPosition(reader.Consumed - delimiter.Length);
    }
}
```

Here are some test cases too:

```
var cases = new List<byte[]>
{
    // Case 1: Check an empty array
    new byte[0],
    // Case 2: Check an array with no delimiter
    new byte[] { 0xf },
    // Case 3: Check an array with part of the delimiter
    new byte[] { 0x1c },
    // Case 4: Check an array with the other part of the delimiter
    new byte[] { 0x0d },
    // Case 5: Check an array with the delimiter in the wrong order
    new byte[] { 0x0d, 0x1c },
    // Case 6: Check an array with a correct delimiter
    new byte[] { 0x1c, 0x0d },
    // Case 7: Check an array with a byte followed by a correct delimiter
    new byte[] { 0x1, 0x1c, 0x0d },
    // Case 8: Check an array with multiple correct delimiters
    new byte[] { 0x1, 0x1c, 0x0d, 0x2, 0x1c, 0x0d },
    // Case 9: Check an array with multiple correct delimiters
    // where the delimiter isn't the last byte
    new byte[] { 0x1, 0x1c, 0x0d, 0x2, 0x1c, 0x0d, 0x3 },
    // Case 10: Check an array with multiple sequential bytes of a delimiter
    new byte[] { 0x1, 0x1c, 0x0d, 0x2, 0x1c, 0x1c, 0x0d, 0x3 },
};

var delimiter = new byte[] { 0x1c, 0x0d };
foreach (var item in cases)
{
    var source = new ReadOnlySequence<byte>(item);
    var result = source.LastPositionOf(delimiter);
} // Put a breakpoint here and examine result
```

Cases `1` to `5` all correctly return `null`. Cases `6` to `10` all correctly return the `SequencePosition` to the first byte in the delimiter (i.e. in this case, `0x1c`).

I also tried to create an iterative version that would yield a position after finding a delimiter, like so:

```
while (reader.TryReadTo(out _, delimiterToFind, true))
{
    yield return reader.Sequence.GetPosition(reader.Consumed - delimiter.Length);
}
```

But `SequenceReader<T>` and `ReadOnlySpan<T>` can't be used in iterator blocks, so I came up with `AllPositionsOf` instead:

```
public static IEnumerable<SequencePosition> AllPositionsOf(
    this ReadOnlySequence<byte> source,
    byte[] delimiter)
{
    if (delimiter == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(delimiter));
    }
    if (!delimiter.Any())
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(delimiter)} is empty", nameof(delimiter));
    }

    var reader = new SequenceReader<byte>(source);
    var delimiterToFind = new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(delimiter);

    var results = new List<SequencePosition>();
    while (reader.TryReadTo(out _, delimiterToFind, true))
    {
        results.Add(reader.Sequence.GetPosition(reader.Consumed - delimiter.Length));
    }

    return results;
}
```

The test cases work properly for that, too.

#### Update

Now that I've had some sleep, and a chance to think about things, I think the above can be improved for a few reasons:

1. `SequenceReader<T>` has a `Rewind()` method, which makes me think `SequenceReader<T>` is designed to be reused
2. `SequenceReader<T>` seems to be designed to make it easier to work with `ReadOnlySequence<T>`s in general
3. Creating an extension method on `ReadOnlySequence<T>` in order to use a `SequenceReader<T>` to read from a `ReadOnlySequence<T>` seems backwards

Given the above, I think it probably makes more sense to try to avoid working directly with `ReadOnlySequence<T>`s where possible, preferring, and reusing, `SequenceReader<T>` instead. So with that in mind, here's a different version of `LastPositionOf` which is now an extension method on `SequenceReader<T>`:

```
public static class SequenceReaderExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Finds the last occurrence of a delimiter in a given sequence.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="reader">The reader to read from.</param>
    /// <param name="delimiter">The delimeter to look for.</param>
    /// <param name="rewind">If true, rewinds the reader to its position prior to this method being called.</param>
    /// <returns>A SequencePosition if a delimiter is found, otherwise null.</returns>
    public static SequencePosition? LastPositionOf(
        this ref SequenceReader<byte> reader,
        byte[] delimiter,
        bool rewind)
    {
        if (delimiter == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(delimiter));
        }
        if (!delimiter.Any())
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(delimiter)} is empty", nameof(delimiter));
        }

        var delimiterToFind = new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(delimiter);
        var consumed = reader.Consumed;

        var delimiterFound = false;
        // Keep reading until we've consumed all delimiters
        while (reader.TryReadTo(out _, delimiterToFind, true))
        {
            delimiterFound = true;
        }

        if (!delimiterFound)
        {
            if (rewind)
            {
                reader.Rewind(reader.Consumed - consumed);
            }

            return null;
        }

        // If we got this far, we've consumed bytes up to,
        // and including, the last byte of the delimiter,
        // so we can use that to get the starting byte
        // of the delimiter
        var result = reader.Sequence.GetPosition(reader.Consumed - delimiter.Length);
        if (rewind)
        {
            reader.Rewind(reader.Consumed - consumed);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

The above test cases continue to pass for this, but we can now reuse the same `reader`. In addition, it allows you to specify if you want to rewind to the original position of `reader` prior to being called.

Comment: so instead of using your first approach for the sequence I could now do something like `SequenceReader<byte> sequenceReader = new SequenceReader<byte>(buffer);
            SequencePosition? lastPosition = sequenceReader.LastPositionOf(delimiters, false);` right? My test passes at least :)